# Possible to find rotation around x, y, z axes by knowing the polar angles $\phi, \theta$?

Tags: geometry, 3d, rotations, python

I'm working with a 3D cartesian system $\vec{e'_x},\vec{e'_y},\vec{e'_z}$ that moves around in a global coordinate system. I know the origo position and $\vec{e'_z}$ in global coordinates. There is no rotation around the z-axis, only around x and y.

How can I find rotation angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ around x, y, z, axes respectively, if I know the new z-direction $\vec{e}_z' = (\cos\theta\sin\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos\phi)$. I know how to compute $\theta, \phi$. And I assume $\gamma = 0$.

My attempt was as follows but it didn't work out.
Compute $cos(\alpha) = ||\vec{e}_{zx}||$, where $\vec{e}_{zx}$ is the projection onto yz-plane i.e. $\vec{e}_z$ with x-component = 0. Then compute $cos(\beta) = ||\vec{e}_{zy}||$, where $\vec{e}_{zy}$ has y-component = 0.

\begin{equation}
    R = R_xR_y, \;\; \text{where}
    \label{rotation_matrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{align*}
    R_x &= 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & \cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha\\
        0 & \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    R_y &= 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \cos\beta & 0 & \sin\beta\\
        0 & 1 & 0\\
        -\sin\beta & 0 & \cos\beta
    \end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}

Code:

```
new_axis = [ 0.03807563 -0.06572909  0.99711079]   # computed before
proj_x = np.multiply(new_axis, np.array([0,1,1]))  # project to yz plane
proj_y = np.multiply(new_axis, np.array([1,0,1]))  # project to xz plane
alfa = np.arccos(norm(proj_x)) # rotation around x
beta = np.arccos(norm(proj_y)) # rotation around y
Rx = np.array([[1,0,0],
               [0, cos(alfa), -sin(alfa)],
               [0, sin(alfa), cos(alfa)]])
Ry = np.array([[cos(beta), 0, sin(beta)],
               [0,1,0],
               [-sin(beta), 0, cos(beta)]])
Rz = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
               [0, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 1]])
R = np.matmul(np.matmul(Rx, Ry), Rz)
```

EDIT: I found that Rodrigues' rotation formula solves this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula.

Comment: In "no rotation around the z-axis", do you mean the one from the local basis? Essentially meaning that the local y-direction points upwards in the global coordinates, or that the x-direction is horizontal, assuming that the z-direction is a forwards direction in some sense?

Comment: Yes exactly, the z-axis is forward in a sense with y pointing up and x to the side. What I am assuming is that the rotation angle around z is 0, so that Rz is the identity matrix.

Comment: To add is that I know the directions of x- and y at the beginning, for my first z-direction.

Comment: And in the global system you also have up=y, so indeed you need to rotate around the y-axis to align the the global and local z direction, and then rotate around the x-axis to get equality in the z-directions. So the spherical coordinates are to be constructed from $\vec e_z=(\cos\phi\cos\theta,\sin\theta, \sin\phi\cos\theta)$, then use the angles as parameters in the rotations.

Comment: Thank you, but I still struggle to actually compute the angles. In this you describe, I guess $\phi$ would be the same as $\beta$ I had, but $\theta$ would correspond to the rotation around z-axis?

Comment: Is the $\vec{e}_z$ you described the new z-axis in the 'old' local coordinates?

Comment: Yes. The orientation in the polar coordinates might be wrong, so a switch of sine and cosine or of the sign of an angle might be necessary to be compatible with existing procedures.

Comment: $\vec{e}_z$ should be (sin$\phi$cos$\theta$, sin$\phi$sin$\theta$, cos$\phi$) I guess, how did you get something else? Which means rotation $\theta$ around z-axis but the problem of 'breaking' the now introduced $\phi$ which rotates around xy-plane into two angles that rotate around x and y respectively remains..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $z$ vector is given as $\vec e_z=(z_1,z_2,z_3)^T$. The aim is to decompose it using axis rotations, which in a 3D context are Givens rotations. A rotation around axis $e_3$ is to be avoided. Thus find angles $α,β$ such that
$$
R_{3,1}(-β)\vec e_z=\pmatrix{0\\*\\*},~~~R_{3,1}=R_y
$$
and
$$
R_{2,3}(-α)R_{3,1}(-β)\vec e_z=\pmatrix{0\\0\\*},~~~R_{2,3}=R_x.
$$
For the first you need $(\cosβ,\sinβ)\sim (z_3,z_1)$ or

```
beta = arctan2(z_1,z_3)
z_1,z_3 = 0, hypot(z_1,z_3)
```

As a result, $(z_1,z_3)$ get replaced by $(z_1',z_3')=(0,\sqrt{z_1^2+z_3^3})$.

Now to determine $α$ we want $(\cosα,\sinα)\sim(z_3',-z_2)$ or

```
alfa = arctan2(-z_2,z_3)
z_2,z_3 = 0, hypot(z_2,z_3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this gives me reasonable results!

Comment: Do you think this solution is possible to extend to include rotation around z as well? For this case I don't need it but interesting to have if possible.

Comment: No, all information is used up. If you have a vector of length $n$ it is reduced to the multiple of some basis vector using $n-1$ Givens rotations. Or did you mean replacing one of the rotation axis with the $z$ axis? Then yes, here you can replace $R_y$ with $R_z$ in the first step. The resulting local basis will have a different orientation in space, with the same z vector of course.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you again for the responses this started to cause me a lot of headache :D

Comment: Yes, computing Euler angles or jaw-pitch-roll heavily depends on the order of rotation axes, and almost all orders are in use somewhere. I find it most simple to liken this to QR decomposition via Given rotations using different elimination orders.

Answer (score 0):

If you find $R_x R_y$ as given in your question, you get

$ R = R_x R_y = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && \cos \alpha && -\sin \alpha \\ 0 && \sin \alpha && \cos \alpha \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \cos \beta && 0 && \sin \beta \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ -\sin \beta && 0 && \cos \beta \end{bmatrix} $

And this is equal to

$R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \beta && 0 && \sin \beta \\ \sin \alpha \sin \beta && \cos \alpha && - \sin \alpha \cos \beta \\ - \cos \alpha \sin \beta && \sin \alpha && \cos \alpha \cos \beta \end{bmatrix} $

Since you know $\vec{e'_z} = (x_3, y_3, z_3) $, then you know the third column of $R$, therefore,

$ \beta = \sin^{-1} (x_3)  , \alpha = \text{Atan2}( y_3, -y_2 ) $